# I've started using Stage3D. Which of these classes are usable in Stage3D?

Tags: actionscript, stage3d

Are these classes supported in Stage3D? Or are there equivalents or similar classes that exist?

```
flash.display.BitmapData;
flash.display.GraphicsSolidFill;
flash.display.GraphicsStroke;
flash.display.GraphicsPath;
flash.display.IGraphicsData;
flash.display.Shape;
flash.filters.BlurFilter;
flash.geom.ColorTransform;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stage3D is an entirely different, fairly low-level beast.  Those classes you list there are all related to the traditional Flash DisplayList, which is a CPU-driven rendering engine, so no, they don't exist, per se.  But there's much more to it than that:

If you're using the raw Stage3D APIs (example [tutorial here](http://www.plugin.io/2011/10/stage3d-tutorial-part-1/)), then it feels very much like OpenGL programming.  You're loading Vertex buffers, Index buffers, and textures into the GPU, and defining Vertex and fragment shader programs in an assembly language called AGAL.  All this gets you a cross-platform, hardware accelerated application that's probably very fast, but it's very different than the traditional Flash DisplayList.  Can you get gradients, filters and vector shapes - sure, but probably with custom shaders and such, not using those classes.

In some applications, it makes sense to use the traditional DisplayList for interactive UI controls on top of the Stage3D hardware accelerated backdrop.  The DisplayList sits on top of the Stage3D plane, so this is entirely possible.

However, if such low-level 3D programming is not what you're interested in, you can choose to build on top of a framework.  There are many Stage3D frameworks - some are intended for creating 3D applications, others are intended for 2D (but using the underlying 3D acceleration for speed).  Adobe has a list of these frameworks [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.edu.html).

For example, [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) is a Stage3D framework that's intended to mimic the traditional Flash DisplayList, so it'll get you close to some of the classes you've mentioned above - check out their [demo](http://gamua.com/starling/first-steps/#) and [API docs](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/) for specifics.

Another technique that Flash enables is blitting, which generates Bitmaps for 3D acceleration on the fly.  You can draw into Bitmaps (aka blit) any Flash DisplayObjects you like (Shapes, drawn gradients, with filters, whatever), then push those Bitmaps into the 3D acceleration framework.  You can blit individual objects separately, or blit the entire stage into one full-screen texture using this technique.  But you have to be careful how often and how much you upload new textures into the GPU, because this can affect performance significantly.  In fact, a significant performance consideration in GPU programming is the ability to batch several bitmaps into a single texture.

So there are many facets to consider when thinking about transitioning from the traditional DisplayList to Stage3D.  Hope this helps.  :)